# Как распарсить строку GraphQL response в POJO объект?

Tags: java, graphql, pojo

Пытаюсь работать с данными в формате GraphQL, Я научился пользоваться библиотекой MountCloud/graphql-client для отправки запросов на сервер Hasura, и она возвращает ответы в формате строки.

Пример строки:

```
{data={product=[{name=Василиск, color=Белый, created_at=2020-02-02T00:00:00+00:00, secret=false}, {name=Falcon Heavy, color=Белый, created_at=2021-02-02T00:00:00+00:00, secret=false}]}}
```

Я нашёл много библиотек  на ГитХабе, например glitr, но ни при помощи одной из них мне не удалось сделать парсинг строки в объект, или хотя-бы в коллекцию Map. Большинство мануалов которые удалось нагуглить выполняют обратный функционал - из объекта в строку GraphQL. Подскажите, существуют готовые решения клиентов/парсеров на java ?